# groupadd: group 'xxxx' already exist

Tags: 14.04, command-line

I have created a group in Ubuntu terminal called `terminal` using `groupadd terminal` command and when I list out the groups using `groups` command it will not show the newly created group name in the output but if I add the same group again it gives me

```
groupadd: group 'terminal' already exists
```

error message but the group name exists in `/etc/group` file. Why I am not able to see the newly added group while running `group` command?

Comment: muru: can you please check that question problem and this question

Comment: I did. Can you do that too?

Comment: so you are telling usermod will solve my problem ? is it ?

Comment: I prefer `adduser` (second answer) or `gpasswd`, but yes.

Answer (score 14):

`groups` shows you **your** groups and not all. You could list all groups for example like that:

```
getent group
```

If you added yourself to the group, you'll need to logout and login for the change to take effect.

Comment: Jakob: if groups shows my groups then the added group generally goes under whom ? If I wanted to added group under me then how do I do that ?

Comment: @Suresh it doesn't go "under" anybody, it just is. A group without any members. If you want to add your user to a group, see the question I linked to.